# Palantir Foundry Incremental decorator: does changing the Column-Ordering require a Semantic versioning update?

Tags: sql, pyspark, dataset, palantir-foundry

In Palantir Foundry I was running a transformation with @incremental decorator for a long.
Now I have to change the ordering of columns (no change in schema though).

Does that require a semantic-version update?

I have followed this [palatir foundry documentation](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/incremental-reference/#requirements-for-incremental-computation) but not very clear.

Comment: its not straightforward.  you can work around it, save the previous version, change the schema which will reset the dataset and then union it back to previous version, and then run the incremental back again
have a look here https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/incremental-examples/

Comment: Can you try it on a branch and see?

Answer (score 1):

This works. You don't need to bump the semantic version and the column will "get aligned".

Testing code, so that you can validate yourself:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output, incremental
import random


# Generation of empty dataframe, that just appends the current timestamp
def get_empty_df(ctx, other_order=False):
    if other_order:
        schema = T.StructType([T.StructField("value", T.StringType(), True), T.StructField("key", T.StringType(), True)])
        df = ctx.spark_session.createDataFrame([("dummy_value_left", "dummy_key")], schema)

    else:
        schema = T.StructType([T.StructField("key", T.StringType(), True), T.StructField("value", T.StringType(), True)])
        df = ctx.spark_session.createDataFrame([("dummy_key", "dummy_value_right")], schema)

    df = df.withColumn('when', F.current_timestamp())
    return df


@incremental(semantic_version=2)
@transform(
    out=Output("/path/output_df")
)
def out_1(ctx, out):
    random_value = random.random()  # random number in range [0.0,1.0)

    df = get_empty_df(ctx, random_value < 0.5)

    # build all the time and append the timestamp
    # out.set_mode("modify") # rely on default behavior
    out.write_dataframe(df)
```

[image]